# Hover effect over div with image and text

Tags: html, css, image, background, opacity

I provide a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/om83Ljtm/

It contains of a `div`, `img`, and `span` element. The `img` acts as a background-image to the `div`. I do not use CSS `background`-property for the background-image because I want to change the opacity when hovering the `div`. The `span` contains text which overlaps the background image. When hovering the `div`, I want to change the opacity of the image. This works, however, when the mouse hovers the text (`span`), the opacity of the `img` changes back to the initial value 0.6. But I want the image to not (!) change back its opacity when I hover over the text. How can this be achieved?

To sum up: In the JSFiddle, if I hover over the `div`, the opacity changes to 1. This should remain, even if I hover over the text in the `span`. This does not work, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.event:hover img` instead of `.event img:hover`

```css
.event {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  height: auto;
}

.event .titel {
  float:left;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color:white;
  padding:3px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:5px;
}

.event img {
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 100%;
}

.event img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.event:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="event">
   <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300">
  <span class="titel">text text text text text text text text text </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by giving hover to div not on img here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/om83Ljtm/2/

```
.event:hover img {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this ;)

```css
.event {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  height: auto;
}

.event .titel {
    float:left;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color:white;
    padding:3px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:5px;
}

.event img {
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 100%;
}

.event img {
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.event:hover img { /* Just change this */
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="event">
   <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300">
  <span class="titel">text text text text text text text text text </span>
</div>
```